# cant translate text in java using google api

Tags: java, api, jsf, google-translator-toolkit

I need to translate texts sent from jsf form to managed beans from english to russian. I used the API provided by google translate. it does not work When i try to translate texts received from jsf page there is no error but i get "????". I dont know why is this happening. But when i used the same thing in different java project it works fine. Can anyone please tell me ?

```
public String translate(String fname){
      Translator translator =Translator.getInstance();
      System.out.println("data received from jsf form =" +fname);

      String russian= translator.translate(fname, Language.ENGLISH, Language.RUSSIAN);
      System.out.println(" translated text of the form  "+russian);
      String staticText = "This is static text inside the function";
      String russian2= translator.translate(staticText, Language.ENGLISH, Language.RUSSIAN);
      System.out.println("Translated static text = "+russian2);
          return russian;
      }
```

Output:

data received from jsf form =Teddy
INFO:   translated text of the form  ?????
INFO:   Translated static text = ??? ??????????? ????? ?????? ???????

Different project file:

```
Translator translate = Translator.getInstance() ;
       String text1 ="translator in in action now ";
String text = translate.translate(text1, Language.ENGLISH, Language.RUSSIAN);
System.out.println("tranlated text =  "+text);
```

Output:
run:
tranlated text =  переводчик в действии Теперь в

Comment: Does it work from a plain java class? In a 'main' If not, it is not jsf related.

Comment: Where does the `System.out.println()` end up in? The console of your IDE? Is that IDE Eclipse?

Comment: This works for this :¨package TEST;

import com.gtranslate.Language;
import com.gtranslate.Translator;

public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Translator translate = Translator.getInstance() ;
       String text1 ="translator in in action now ";
String text = translate.translate(text1, Language.ENGLISH, Language.RUSSIAN);
System.out.println("tranlated text =  "+text);
    }
}

Comment: This works for this :                                                                                          package TEST;
//import
public class NewMain {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Translator translate = Translator.getInstance() ;
      
String text = translate.translate(" in action now ", Language.ENGLISH, Language.RUSSIAN);
System.out.println(text);
    }
}

Comment: i m using NetBeans 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks possible for me that something with the Cyrillic encoding is wrong in the place where you want to print the result of your method.

Comment: thank you my fren but can you please tell me in detail and if possible also solution to fix it ?

Comment: Where do you try the print the result of this method? In the standard output or in another app?